# Creating updated field in ArcGIS for desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, attribute-table, python-parser

This is my attribute table:

[image]

the field "hight" is short type.

the field "text" is string type.

I try to find how can i connect between those two field with python phrase (i know how to do it with python phrase) but whats importent to me is that if i change the field "hight", then the new field will update automaticlly.

I red [Automatically updating column in feature class when another column is changed?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109551/automatically-updating-column-in-feature-class-when-another-column-is-changed) but this isn't what i seek because it clumsy and long solution. I need a simple python\ Vb phrase to implement in the Field Calculator of the layer.